# Custom password policy for spring boot from file after build

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, web-config

My scenario below:

1. I have a web application which I am building using spring boot .
2. I want to a create a configuration file PolicyPassword (which may be .property, .xml...) to set some policy for passwords Ex: 

    - Max/min length

    - Allow special characters..
3. After building the war and deploying it to tomcat, I  want to sometime change the configurations in the file PolicyPassword without re-building the  web app. The changes should reflect immediately in my application

I really don't know where to start :(. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Spring-Cloud-Config.

You can read more about it here -

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html

What you will basically do is spin up a config Server. You can keep all your configuration files in one place i.e. in git,svn,local file system or vault and tell configServer where they lie.

All, you will need to do is in  your spring boot application , add the dependency of spring cloud config Client and configure properties telling the configClient where the configServer lies. On your application startup, the configClient will query ConfigServer for the property files, which the configServer will respond with and the ConfigClient will add the properties to  Spring's Environment.

As for your exact question, you can change your properties in the file which you store in git,svn,local filesystem,vault etc, whatever you like, and then call the /refresh endpoint in your client application, which will force it to fetch the latest properties from the ConfigServer.

Also, you can store your properties encrypted and have decryption on the client or server side.

This is a good tutorial to get started with -

https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/